# PHP echo HTML from MySQL Inserting as Sibling not Child

Tags: php, html, mysql, dom

I have a PHP page that is pulling data from a MySQL table. One field (content) contains HTML to populate on the page. When trying to insert the record inside of a paragraph tag, the result starts and ends with a paragraph tag, but does not insert correctly as a child element, but as a sibling. Can anyone see the issue here?

HTML/PHP

```
<?php
foreach ($pages as $page) {
?>
                <div class="slide" id="about-content">
                    <h1 class="pic-title"><?=$page->title;?></h1>
                    <p class="pic-caption overlay">
                        <?=$page->content;?>
                    </p>
                </div>
<?php
}
?>
```

Output HTML:

```
<div class="fp-tableCell" style="height:419px;">
   <h1 class="pic-title" style="margin-left: 25px;">Splash Page 2</h1>
   <p class="pic-caption overlay" style="display: block;">
   </p>
   <p>dfajdfn<strong>akdjfnas</strong></p>
   <p></p>
</div>
```

MySQL Data:

- Title: Splash Page 2
- Content: `<p>dfajdfn<strong>akdjfnas</strong></p>`

I can't seem to trace this one. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's to be expected, you're inserting a `<p>` inside another `<p>`. You can **NOT** nest paragraphs, and starting a new paragraph while inside a paragraph will terminate the earlier one.
e.g.

```
<p>foo
<p>bar
<p>baz
```

will internally generate

```
<p>foo</p>
<p>bar</p>
<p>baz</p>
```

In the DOM tree.

You should probably switch to using `<div>` instead:

```
<div class="pic-caption overlay">
 ^^^---
    <?=$page->content;?>
</div>
  ^^^
```

Comment: Same. You got the answer up too quick for me :) +1

Comment: That's fantastic this one slipped past me, p within a p, what was I thinking.